# How to compute a slowly converging series to 10 decimals places of accuracy?

Tags: numerical-methods, project-euler

I'm looking at a Project Euler problem, where a harmonic series is modified such that it excludes terms where a digit appears three times consecutively in the denominator. So this series would exclude 1/111, 1/222, 1/1000, 1/1112, 1/2221, etc.

It turns out that this series is convergent, albeit very, very slowly. If I need to calculate the sum of this series up to 10 decimal places of accuracy, is there a way of doing this without brute force?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the method from Euler to accelerate the convergence ?

Comment: Hi Peter, I do not.

Comment: Look at wikipedia series acceleration, where euler's transform and some other methods are shown.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look at Euler transformation and looks like it applies only to alternating series, so not applicable here. But will explore some of the other methods.